# What is better UI for graph function editor between spline and bezier

Tags: user-interface, graph, bezier, spline

I am trying to make a game system that can weight decision of AI or success chance of things in game into graph function that can be edited

Problem is, I don't want to implement many kind of graph. I want to use only one formula for curve function

Which now I can't decide between 3rd order bezier, like vector path in PhotoShop, has 2 control point for each point

Or a spline that auto approximate bezier to pass all the point but need to add point if you want to control how it curve

Which one do you think is more convenient to use and also easier to implement and prevent bug?

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend is a combination of both. You create the curve as a Catmull-Rom spline that pass through all the points with one cubic Bezier curve in between each two consecutive points. Then, you present the control points to users allowing them to fine tune the shape of the curve.